# Move Questions Up and Down - PHP

Tags: php

For the system that I have, it uses the following code to produce the questions in position order:

```
foreach ($questionnaire->questions->sortBy('position_number') as $question)
```

Want I want to be able to do is for each question id to gain access to a previous question id and a next question id. So if I am on question id 1 that has a position of 3 for example, I would want to be able to access question id 3 that has a position of 2 and question id 5 that has a position of 4.

Comment: We have no idea how to do that without more information about your classes and what you actually want to do. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF AND ONLY IF** the array is a sequential array, the following code should work:

```
$myArray = ($questionnaire->questions->sortBy('position_number');
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
{
  $keyPrev = $key - 1;
  $keyNext = $key + 1;

  echo "Next value is ".$myArray[$keyNext]."<br>";
  echo "Current value is ".$value."<br>";
    //OR
  echo "Current value is ".$myArray[$key]."<br>";

  if ($key > 0)
  echo "Previous value was ".$myArray[$keyPrev]."<br>";
}
```

remember to check `if ($key > 0)` before using `$keyPrev` because in the first iteration, you are still going to calculate a $keyPrev and that $keyPrev will be invalid.

Comment: That might explain as to why I am not receiving the correct values then. I seem to be receiving the index of the for-each loop, rather than the actual question id values. Because each set of questions in a questionnaire is going to have a unique position number, could I do a where statement on each position and get the question ids that way? That's once the user clicks on a up or down button. It will probably be quite messy if I try and convert the way to a sequential one.

Comment: @userrandomuser there is a good chance. It probably depends on how you created the array. You could go to the sortBy function, and make it so that it is sequential on creation, and that should solve it also :)

Comment: OK. I decided to do something similar to this with the position numbers, rather than the question ids. This approach works. Thank you!

Comment: @userrandomuser no problem! if this solution worked for you, please accept the answer so that future users can know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Grab the keys of the array using `array_keys()` and then `foreach` as usual. Use a counter to help keep track which key you are on. This will work even with non-numerical indexes.

```
$counter = 0;
// store it so that we can access it however we like
$questions = $questionnaire->questions->sortBy('position_number');
// get an array of keys of the $questions array. They are returned in order.
$questionKeys = array_keys($questions);
// use to check that there is a next question
$countKeys = count($keys) - 2;

foreach($questions as $question) {
  // only want to access the previous question if there is a previous question
  if ($counter > 0) {
    $previousQuestion = $questions[$questionKeys[$counter - 1]];
    // do interesting things with the previous question
  }

  // only access the next question if there is a next question
  if ($counter < $countKeys) {
    $nextQuestion = $questions[$questionKeys[$counter + 1]];
    //do interesting things
  }
  $counter++;
}
```